# Error installing apache 2 in ubuntu 14.04: dpkg:- error processing package javascript-common (--configure):

Tags: apache, installation, ubuntu-14.04, apt

I was trying to reinstall my apache 2 after un-installing it. But on installing it using command-

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

I am getting error-

```
rahul@rahulpc:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2
[sudo] password for rahul: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libblas3 liblinear-tools liblinear1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 474 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up javascript-common (11) ...
dpkg: error processing package javascript-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 javascript-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think I have removed some essential directories while un-installing apache 2 . Anybody please help me to recover the files and to install apache 2.

Comment: As per the message, it seem like you didnt uninstall apache2. Try with
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following commands:

`sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean`

- **Clean** clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.
- Like clean, **autoclean** clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. The difference is that it only removes package files that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless. This allows a cache to be maintained over a long period without it growing out of control.

`sudo apt-get purge apache2`

- **Purge** is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration files are deleted too).

Before installing apache2, try running this:
`sudo apt-get update`

- **Update** is used to resynchronize the package index files from their sources.

`sudo apt-get install apache2`